# GWT JavaScriptObject reading "delete" property

Tags: gwt, javascript-objects

I have the following native method in a extended JavaScriptObject class:

```
public final native boolean getDelete()  /*-{ return this.delete; }-*/;
```

but this apparently doesn't work as "delete" is an javascript operator.

How can I read this property correctly.

The thrown exception is:

**com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParserException: missing name after . operator**

Comment: you cannot rename the property "delete" in your JavaScriptObject?

Comment: No ... I have no control over it (read external system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it by accessing it as string:

```
public final native boolean getDelete()  /*-{ return this['delete']; }-*/;
```

Comment: This is it ... every property can be accessed from a hash table.